# Meteor - How to use Blaze.renderWithData in a bootbox and have the result remain reactive?

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-blaze, bootbox

I am using the following:

```
let box = bootbox.dialog({title:'',message:''});
box.find('.bootbox-body').remove();
Blaze.renderWithData(template,doc,box.find(".modal-body")[0]);
```

It renders correctly, but is not reactive.

I suspect I have a problem passing in the doc directly, and have the _id of the doc available.

What should I be passing to renderWithData in order for the result to be reactive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution.

Instead of

```
let doc = MyCollection.findOne({_id});
Blaze.renderWithData(template,doc,box.find(".modal-body")[0]);
```

Or

```
Blaze.renderWithData(template,MyCollection.findOne({_id}),box.find(".modal-body")[0]);
```

I switched to

```
Blaze.renderWithData(template,function(){
  MyCollection.findOne({_id})
},box.find(".modal-body")[0]);
```

This now makes the dialog reactive.

Answer (score 0):

If in the code before the bootbox you have `doc = MyCollection.findOne(...)` then `doc` will be reactive. Otherwise you can pass in the `_id` and perform the `.find()` in your template helper (the one you are passing into `Blaze.render()`.

Comment: 1) actually, doc was loaded using doc = MyCollection.findOne({_id}), but pass the result into Blaze.renderWithData, and it no longer is reactive.

Comment: 2) I'm not sure how you can pass the _id into Blaze.renderWithData. It is expecting data, not the _id.

Comment: Depends how the template is setup and what its helpers are. It's expecting a _data context_ which can be just about anything from a cursor to an array of objects to a single object to a scalar value.